# Flush specific Redis DB using a single command

Tags: linux, shell, redis, console

In order to flush some specific redis database, I need to do the following:

- Enter the Redis interactive CLI (`> redis-cli`)
- Select a database (`> select 0`)
- Flush the db (`> flushdb`)

But is there a way to run these 2 interactive commands as a single shell command? I can only pass one command to the interactive application using the pipe: `"echo select 0" | redis-cli`, but not both of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can select the database with the call to the cli using the `-n` switch.

For running more than one command, redirect a file instead of piping an echo, or feed the cli raw protocol with the `--pipe` switch.